# Get fossil to accept several tags on commit?

Tags: fossil

I would really like if I could do something like:

```
fossil commit --tag 0.1.2 release
```

and have fossil add both `0.1.2` and `release` as tags.

How can I accomplish this?

**Edit:**
I built the fossil on windows as suggested and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeat the `--tag` option multiple times like `fossil commit --tag 0.1.2 --tag release`

```
d:\test>fossil new test
project-id: 6cf7c1419425e47a71c35900179cb879a68fe495
server-id:  3a9e9a972204274d5a137b9e50df9a54928c4f96
admin-user: Eigenaar (initial password is "846ac5")

d:\test>fossil open test

d:\test>echo hello >world

d:\test>fossil add world
ADDED  world

d:\test>fossil commit --comment "First release" --tag 0.1.2 --tag release
New_Version: 761d2a6c3be8fc22413b5ddedbab46e5500b1b38

d:\test>fossil info
project-name: <unnamed>
repository:   d:/test/test
local-root:   d:/test/
user-home:    C:/Users/Eigenaar/AppData/Local
project-code: 6cf7c1419425e47a71c35900179cb879a68fe495
checkout:     761d2a6c3be8fc22413b5ddedbab46e5500b1b38 2012-07-09 21:13:17 UTC
parent:       1099fa0a0516d4b8a57306c4ee449f86a44f534d 2012-07-09 21:13:17 UTC
tags:         trunk, 0.1.2, release
comment:      First release (user: Eigenaar)
```

Comment: I tried your approach, but I get the following error: "`unrecognized command-line option, or missing argument: --tag`". I have fossil version 1.22.

Comment: My version is also 1.22 but I compiled it myself using the latest sourcecode. The 'allow multiple tags' feature was added to fossil with checkin http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/info/c4dc635e6b on March 20th, a few days after the release of version 1.22. You can compile a new version yourself or wait for version 1.23

Comment: I will give it a try. Can you recommend a way to compile under windows? I have tried several methods from http://www.fossil-scm.org/fossil/wiki?name=compillingOnWindows but they seem outdated.

Comment: I used Microsoft Visual C++ (2008) to compile it but it required some changes to the makefile and downloading a zlib library from the Internet. Somehow my fossil.exe now depends on a zlib1.dll :-) If I were you I would wait for the next 'official' release. Version 1.22 was over three months ago so I expect a new release soon.

Comment: Forgot to give you the bounty. Very helpful indeed. I think I'll add the compilation to the fossil wiki.

Comment: For your information: Fossil 1.23 was released today. From its release notes: "Allow multiple --tag options on the same "fossil commit" command."  http://www.fossil-scm.org/download.html